# mysql sorting a database table with no foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have been given some legacy mysql database (about 50k rows) to work with. Basically, the database table has the following structure (flat structure, no foreign keys)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| IDENTIFIER | Release Year | Category | Album Reviews | Artist |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    1       |  1981        | Rock     | abc.com       | GNR    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    2       |  2000        | Pop      | xyz.com       | JayZ   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    3       |  2001        | Pop      | jkl.com       | Spears |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    4       |  1981        | Rock     | onm.com       | GNR    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    5       |  2000        | Pop      | qwe.com       | JayZ   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    6       |  2001        | Pop      | vgh.com       | Spears |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, each artist, has an album released in a particular year, and the album reviews are available on pages specified in column "Album Reviews". However, the table has some "duplicates", which is that there are multiple "Album Review's" for each artist.

What I would like is to arrange the above mysql table as follows (assuming I want to restrict myself to only 2 album reviews):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| IDENTIFIER | Release Year | Category | Album Reviews1 | Album Reviews2 | Artist |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1       |  1981        | Rock     | abc.com        | onm.com        | GNR    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2       |  2000        | Pop      | xyz.com        | qwe.com        | JayZ   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3       |  2001        | Pop      | jkl.com        | vgh.com        | Spears |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, there could be multiple (more than 2 and upto 5) album reviews. The problem is I cant use any foreign keys (for the curious, it is because the db table will be later used with django and haystack later).

Is it possible to achieve the above structure? I did try googling around, but couldn't find any sufficient material on how to achieve this.

I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: What you want is called denormalisation. And that is probably not what you should do. What you *should* do is decompose the table into two tables: one for albums, and one for reviews.

Comment: @wildplasser: thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way to decompose the table (automatically)? If you know of any links for this, please let me know.

Comment: Automatically: no (we would all be out of work). But it is reasonably simple: for each field in your original table, choose which of the two new tables it belongs to. (some fields could belong to both, and you'll have to introduce a new (KEY) field). Then create the two tables and fill them with the original, avoiding the duplicates.

Comment: what if i have one more Album Review in year 1981 for GNR? Where are you going to store it?? One more `Album Reviews3`?? What if I have to add `Album Reviews4` when your database already have 10k rows??

Comment: That is excatly my problem Fahim. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: see my answer and let me know if you have any queries...

Comment: @JasonB, I'm just curious for what reason do you need the proposed structure. What is the problem with the original structure with multiple rows per Artist. I think whatever data you will need from the proposed structure can as well be retrieved from the original. No?

Comment: @Abhay, Its a bit more complicated than that. As I have said on the post, the db table will be fed into a stack of django-haystack-solr and the tricky part is no foreign keys are allowed, because of inspectdb in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this simplier, imagine we remove the album reviews columns from both tables. In your example, you ASSUMED that every equal tuple (release year, category and artist) referred to the same album, hence, you created the result with 3 final records. However, as you know, nobody can assume that, so your own example is wrong, because Spears could have had 2 different albums in 2001 for the same category :)

Additionally you might have the same album twice for the same year, but with different categories (this would actually depend on how data was inserted there).

So, what's the problem? As long as you can't find a way to identify each album in your current data there is no way to derive a new table grouped by albums.

**Edit:**

> "you ASSUMED that every equal tuple (release year, category and artist) referred to the same album" ofcourse, there are assumptions and these assumptions are valid for my test case (if that makes sense).

Ok, if those assumptions are valid, then, given the following set of data (I've added some records):

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------------+--------+
| ID | RELEASEYEAR | CATEGORY | ALBUMREVIEWS | ARTIST |
+----+-------------+----------+--------------+--------+
|  1 |        1981 | Rock     | abc.com      | GNR    |
|  2 |        2000 | Pop      | xyz.com      | JayZ   |
|  3 |        2001 | Pop      | jkl.com      | Spears |
|  4 |        1981 | Rock     | onm.com      | GNR    |
|  5 |        2000 | Pop      | qwe.com      | JayZ   |
|  6 |        2001 | Pop      | vgh.com      | Spears |
|  7 |        2001 | Pop      | ppp.com      | Spears |
|  8 |        2003 | Rock     | zzz.com      | Stones |
|  9 |        2007 | Pop      | ppp.com      | Spears |
+----+-------------+----------+--------------+--------+
```

You can get to this result:

```
+-------------+----------+---------------+---------------+--------+
| RELEASEYEAR | CATEGORY | ALBUMREVIEWS1 | ALBUMREVIEWS2 | ARTIST |
+-------------+----------+---------------+---------------+--------+
|        1981 | Rock     | abc.com       | onm.com       | GNR    |
|        2000 | Pop      | xyz.com       | qwe.com       | JayZ   |
|        2001 | Pop      | jkl.com       | vgh.com       | Spears |
|        2003 | Rock     | zzz.com       |               | Stones |
|        2007 | Pop      | ppp.com       |               | Spears |
+-------------+----------+---------------+---------------+--------+
```

By running the following query:

```
select s1.releaseYear, s1.category, max(s1.albumReviews1) as AlbumReviews1,
  max(s1.albumReviews2) as AlbumReviews2, s1.artist
from (
  select t1.releaseYear, t1.category, t1.artist,
    if ((
      select count(*) from t t2
      where t2.releaseYear = t1.releaseYear and t2.category = t1.category and
      t2.artist = t2.artist and t2.id < t1.id
    ) = 0, t1.albumReviews, null) as AlbumReviews1,
    if ((
      select count(*) from t t2
      where t2.releaseYear = t1.releaseYear and t2.category = t1.category and
      t2.artist = t2.artist and t2.id < t1.id
    ) = 1, t1.albumReviews, null) as AlbumReviews2
  from t t1
) as s1
group by s1.releaseYear, s1.category, s1.artist
```

Give it a try and let me know how it works.

Comment: "you ASSUMED that every equal tuple (release year, category and artist) referred to the same album" ofcourse, there are assumptions and these assumptions are valid for my test case (if that makes sense).

Comment: Ok, I've added a possible solution provided that assumption is valid

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is Create two tables.

First one is as below.

```
-------------------------------------------------
| IDENTIFIER | Release Year | Category | Artist |
-------------------------------------------------
|    1       |  1981        | Rock     | GNR    |
-------------------------------------------------
|    2       |  2000        | Pop      | JayZ   |
-------------------------------------------------
|    3       |  2001        | Pop      | Spears |
-------------------------------------------------
```

**NOTE** : In table 1, `IDENTIFIER` is PRIMARY KEY.

Second table will be as below.

```
------------------------------
| IDENTIFIER | Album Reviews |
------------------------------
|    1       | abc.com       |
------------------------------
|    1       | onm.com       |
------------------------------
|    2       | xyz.com       |
------------------------------
|    2       | qwe.com       |
------------------------------
|    3       | jkl.com       |
------------------------------
|    3       | vgh.com       |
------------------------------
```

**NOTE** : In table 2, `IDENTIFIER` is FOREIGN KEY.

This way you can have many records of `Album Reviews` for `IDENTIFIER` (artist for that year).

Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: Fahim, sorry to say, but, as you can see on my post, foreign keys are not allowed :(

Comment: What is the problem of having `FOREIGN` keys??

Comment: The problem is Fahim that the table will be passed to django as a legacy database and therefore cannot contain foreign keys.

Comment: Then don't keep any FOREIGN key... But you will have to make sure that unwanted data will not be inserted. Like here `4-vgh.com` will be an invalid entry. What you can do is create a script that run daily which will check for `IDENTIFIER` that are there in table 2. if IDENTIFIER that you have in table 2 is not present in table 1, then delete those IDENTIFIER. Hope you understand what I meant to say...